# Split String after a specified length but do not break words using groovy

Tags: groovy

I want to split a string into a maximum character length of 40 without breaking the words.It is fine if the string length is less than 40.

How can i achieve this using groovy script in CPI?

e.g Input = "Here you will find programs to get length of the string"

The 40th position lies at letter "g" of word "length"

Output 1:""Here you will find programs to get"
Output 2: "length of the string"

Comment: What have you tried?  Please add your code.  And the errors you got with it.

Comment: I am very new to groovy scripts. So it would be helpful if you could provide with some sample code.

Comment: How would you solve this problem in a different language? E.g. Java? Think of it as a nice algorithmic exercise that can be solved in multiple different ways. Try to solve it and if you run into a specific problem, someone will help you. Copy-pasting free code samples won't help you to learn anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach:

```
    def text = "Here you will find programs to get length of the string"
    def result = (text =~ /(?s)(.{1,40})(?:\s|$)/).collect {
        it[1]
    }

    result.each {
        println it
    }
```

and here is the output

```
Here you will find programs to get
length of the string
```

Comment: Thank You for your response. However the issue is if we have one word (without spaces) of length greater than 40, then it truncates the first characters to get the deired length = 40
e.g

Input String : "Hereyouwillfindprogramstogetlengthofthestring, convert string into character array"
Output1: uwillfindprogramstogetlengthofthestring,
Output2: convert string into character array

Expected Output1: Hereyouwillfindprogramstogetlengthofthes (length 40)
Expected Output2: tring, convert string into character